# Running jupyter notebook on GCP with image TF

Tags: virtual-machines, google-compute-engine

I created a VM machine from image TF (tf-1-10-cu92) to use tensorflow. I found that it includes already jupyter notebook but I can connect to it just the first time. Later I encounter an error

> A connection to the notebook server could not be established. The notebook will continue trying to reconnect. Check your network connection or notebook server configuration

I search for this problem and found that maybe it is because my IP is not static so I did it. [static ip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oFS9o.png)

I also created a firewall rule that allows all protocols [firewall rule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UMCBD.png)

However, the error is not solved. I am very appreciated if someone can help me with this. Thank you

p/s: The command I used to created the VM is below:

```
export IMAGE_FAMILY="tf-1-10-cu92" # 
export ZONE="us-west2-b" # budget: "us-west1-b"
export INSTANCE_NAME="tf-instance"
export INSTANCE_TYPE="n1-highmem-8" # budget: "n1-highmem-4"

# budget: 'type=nvidia-tesla-k80,count=1'
gcloud compute instances create $INSTANCE_NAME \
        --zone=$ZONE \
        --image-family=$IMAGE_FAMILY \
        --image-project=deeplearning-platform-release \
        --maintenance-policy=TERMINATE \
        --accelerator="type=nvidia-tesla-p4,count=1" \
        --machine-type=$INSTANCE_TYPE \
        --boot-disk-size=200GB \
        --metadata="install-nvidia-driver=True" \
        --preemptible
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have already created a firewall rule for all IP and all protocols, what I assume is that your internal firewall might be closed or the service is not listening in any port.

I suggest you to make an [nmap](https://nmap.org/) test such as `sudo nmap -p <port> <your-server-ip>`

If the result is something different to OPEN then that's the issue.

Comment: Do you mean by checking port of my GCP machine (IP found in GCP) ?

If yes then the port is actually
8080/tcp open 

I can access to Jupyter notebook by taping: <GCP-VM-IP>:8080 . The Notebook page load successful. Actually I can use jupyter the first time when I created it. Then, when I shut it down, and move to another place, I cannot use it anymore. So I guess it might come from static or dynamic IP. However, I follow a tutorial and everything is fine. When I open a notebook, it takes forever to load then an error appear "A connection to the notebook server could not be established..."

Comment: Yes, in fact, if you are using an ephemeral IP most likely you'll lose it at some point. I suggest you [reserve a static IP] (https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address) and then update all your configuration to use the one you just reserved

Comment: Yes I reserved the static IP already but it is not working. 
The full error is :"A connection to the notebook server could not be established. The notebook will continue trying to reconnect. Check your network connection or notebook server configuration."

Comment: Please update your case with a nmap test for all your ports and a screenshot of your firewall rules

Comment: You find here the firewall rule: [fire wall](https://i.imgur.com/etIrrsf.png) . You can see the tensortr_rule apply for all port. However, when I try to run the nmap for all ports, it takes really long time. I used the command like this: nmap -p- -T2 -n <ip> . Do you know another way to make it faster. Thank you a lot

Comment: If you want to determine whether the port is open or not you should wait for the output of this command, execute this nmap command without the -T2 flag  `sudo nmap -p 8080  <your-server-ip>` and update the case with the output please